# Change Cognito Currency Symbols

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I change the default currency symbol to £ sterling rather than $ dollars?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question! I'm Nicholas, and I'm a developer for Cognito Forms. Currently we don't support additional currency symbols, but this is a feature that we have on our list for a future release. You can track our progress on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Bkd7xPKv), and see what other features we're working on as well.

Please let us know if there's anything else we can help you with in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) now supports international forms:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/17/building-forms/form-settings